# Añadir google calendar y comparar fechas

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

tengo que crear una aplicación tipo reserva de apartamentos y me han pedido que implemente un formulario tipo Desde: fecha , Hasta: fecha y que los datos los recoga desde Google calendar.
Mi pregunta es , como puedo vincular de alguna manera el google calendar para que reciba la información en los datapicker, no tengo ni zorra de google calendar y tampoco esque haya mucha referencia por ahi, se os ocurre algo?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!
Por favor, cuidemos el lenguaje ;) y deberias ser mas explicito de que queres, que intentaste, que buscaste y que encontraste que no te sirivio.

Comment: Hay [bastante documentación y de muy buena calidad](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php). Sería cuestión de instalar las librerías que ofrece Google (recomiendo que lo hagas con Composer) y luego es cuestión de inspirarte en los ejemplos de Google para empezar con el código. Hay unos pasos previos que al principio parecen engorrosos, tales como crear un proyecto, activar las APIs, decidir el tipo de acceso/credenciales que tienes que crear, etc. De todos modos todo está bien explicado y cuando lo configuras tienes una API potente con la que puedes hacer maravillas.